# how do I override the default purple background color in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-button

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/btn"
    android:text="7"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/txt"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

1. am trying to change the background color, but the color value i give it, its still come out purple

Answer (score 3):

From `colors.xml` or `styles.xml` (themes)

Res -> values -> colors.xml

You can also extend or override themes however you like

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that `background` attr. You can try this.

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="0dp"   
   android:layout_height="70dp"   
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:text="7"
   android:backgroundTint="#9575CD"    
   android:textColor="@color/black"    
   android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a **`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`** theme the default background color of the `Button` (which is replaced by a `MaterialButton`) is the **`colorPrimary`** defined in your app theme.  The default value is the purple.

You can change this value in your app theme defined `styles.xml` o `themes.xml`

If you want to change this color only in the button you can use also the `app:backgroundTint` attribute removing the `android:background` attribute:

```
<Button
    app:backgroundTint="@color/..."/>
```